# Solving the equation $\sin 40^{\circ}=\cos x$

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve this equation (finding $x$ ):

$$\sin 40^\circ=\cos x$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT** $$\sin(y^{\circ}) = \cos(90^{\circ}-y^{\circ})$$

Comment: Typo: you typed hint instead of answer.

Comment: @GitGud: He does that often.;)

Comment: @Marvis why such a tiny joke make you take such major decisions? Don't be insulted so badly by two users of the whole site :)

Comment: @GitGud I think you need to relearn your English.

Comment: @Inceptio: You have been on this site for just $50$ days and I believe you do not have enough sample data to make this statement. Given the OP's level, I believe this is an appropriate **hint**.

Comment: @Ruslan: I invest my time in making this site a better place but when a nincompoop makes a random statement, it does put me off.

Comment: @user17762: $48$ days. :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Hint**:

$\sin \angle BAC= \dfrac{BC}{AC}$ and $\sin\angle  BAC=\cos(90-\angle BAC) =\dfrac{AB}{AC}$. I will let the figure to do the further talking.

Answer (score 0):

sin(40)=coS(50)
because siny = coS(90-y)